# Allocation of memory for return value in function and memory leaks

Tags: c++

I have a function:

```
char const* GetData() const 
{
      char* result = new char[32];
      sprintf(result, "My super string");

      return result;
}
```

Adn then show this string on the screen like this:

```
std::cout << GetData() << std::endl;
```

Or have a class:

```
class MyClass()
{
    char m_data[32]
public:
     MyClass(const char* data) { strcpy(m_data, data) } ;
}
```

And create an instance of an object:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(GetData());
```

I allocate `char* result = new char[32];` and never delete this. How should I deal with memory leak ?  How should I free the memory ?

Comment: Use `std::vector` or `std::string`. There's pretty much no reason to do this another way.

Comment: You can't do `MyClass obj = new MyClass(GetData());`, it won't compile. C++ is not Java, stop using `new` so much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++ [best feature](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/cs-best-feature/) mainly comes from its deterministic object destruction (this is a point originally taken from Bjarne).

It allows the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom. So make sure to read about it, then it should be clear that you should always use objects to manage resources.
Essentially, when you write your program, you know exactly when each object's destructor will be called. So you use that knowledge at your advantage to delegate resource management to an object whose destructor will free your resources (and make sure the object is actually destructed when you want to free the resource ^^)

As pointed in comments, if you need a string of characters, the STL gives you a very good object to manage the underlying dynamic char array lifetime :

```
 std::string
```

### How to rewrite you first method

Taking advantage of the **std::string** facility :

```
std::string GetData() const 
{
     return std::string("My super string");
}
```

But you probably do not need the function here, just create the **std::string** object directly wherever you need it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, always use `std::string` when working with strings in C++. It's safe, fast and efficient.

Secondly, never use a naked pointer when handling dynamic memory (e.g. `char* naked_ptr = new char[32]`). Instead always wrap your pointers in a *smart pointer*, e.g. `std::unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`. If you use smart pointers you don't have to worry about deallocating resources as it's done automatically for you.

**And now to answering your question:**

You can't delete the memory as you have lost the pointer pointing to it.

Your function `GetData` returns a pointer to the memory it allocates dynamically. Then you pass the pointer to the constructor of `MyClass` which uses it to copy the data pointed to. Next the pointer is destroyed as `GetData()` results in a temporary object that only exists during the call to the constructor.

To deallocate the memory you need to keep track of that pointer so you can `delete[]` it.

For example:

```
const char* p = GetData()
MyClass* obj = new MyClass(p); // obj must be a pointer or it won't compile.
/* do stuff */
delete obj; // You should also delete obj.
delete[] p;
```

Or you could use smart pointers like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> p(GetData());
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> obj(new MyClass(p.get()));
/* do stuff */
```

**However**
It's a bad practice to let a function return dynamically allocated memory as it makes the caller responsible to clean up after it.

Comment: Also, `unique_ptr` already supports arrays, use `unique_ptr<char[]>` instead of your custom deleter.

Comment: I disagree that std::string is "fast". Compared to what?

Comment: @NeilKirk I was just trying to emphasize that there's little to no performance penalty when using `std::string` compared to dynamically allocating a `char` array. I often find that people posting on SO use `new char[]` because they are trying to optimize away `std::string`, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I allocate char* result = new char[32]; and never delete this. How
>   should I deal with memory leak ? How should I free the memory ?

```
delete [] result;
```

and with your class,

```
MyClass *obj = new MyClass(...)    
delete obj;
```

Because your function allocates memory and never destroys the array, it's a caller's responsibility to free memory. So if you pass **result** to **MyClass** constructor, you should probably implement delete [] result; in **MyClass** destructor.

Comment: But `MyClass` might be passed a `const char*` which isn't dynamically allocated, e.g. `MyClass m("blah")`, in which case using `delete[]` would be a bug. The problem is not easily soluble, because the design of `GetData` is broken and should be changed

Comment: You won't be able to pass const char * if constructor takes just char *. The design given in this question isn't the one I'd admire, however some linux and windows system functions do that. It is sometimes unavoidable.

Comment: The OP's code has `MyClass(const char*)` though, and in C++03 a string literal has an implicit conversion to `char*` anyway.  The way to cope with APIs that return allocated memory is to wrap it in an RAII type immediately, not to workaround it and spread the disease into other unrelated types such as `MyClass`